# python разобрать файл для импорта в БД

Tags: python

Помогите разобрать файл на куски чтобы перенести информацию в БД.
На выходе хочется иметь удобный формат для БД, например словарь.
Кусков в {} будет несколько тысяч. Нужно каждый засунуть в БД.

```
{
  "obj": "1002",
  "name": "pos-04",
  "pos": null,
  "type": "scanner",
  "prod": "Lenovo",
  "model": "XCV2345",
  "serial": "34767fvfg77",
  "hdd": null
}
{
  "obj": "1002",
  "name": "pos-03",
  "pos": null,
  "type": "scanner",
  "prod": "Lenovo",
  "model": "XCV2345",
  "serial": "34767fvfg77",
  "hdd": null
}{
  "obj": "1002",
  "name": "pos-02",
  "pos": null,
  "type": "scanner",
  "prod": "Lenovo",
  "model": "XCV2345",
  "serial": "34767fvfg77",
  "hdd": null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Помогите разобрать файл на куски

Структура файла, которую вы показали, очень похожа на файл JSON. Если заменить *null* на что то вроде *"None"*, то для считывания одной(!) порции подойдёт нечто вроде:

```
import json

def main():
    # Читаем словарь из файла
    with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.loads(str(f.read()))

    print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

А так как Вам нужно прочитать множество словарей, то надо подумать, как объединить их всех в одну структуру. Может быть будет достаточно просто поставить фигурные скобки в начале и конце файла данных.